# Error while creating table : Syntax error at or near "@"

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions

I am trying to convert SQL Server stored function to PostgreSQL stored function I am getting one syntactical error at `declare @table1 table`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ETL_GetBuildingDetailsByUserID ( p_nInstID   numeric=0)
RETURNS Boolean
AS $$
    declare @table1 table 
    (
    nbuilding numeric(18, 0) NOT NULL,
    sbuild_name varchar(50) NULL,
    sclient_build_id varchar(50) NULL,
    nbuilding_inst_id numeric(18, 0) NOT NULL,
    ntemp_building_id numeric(18,0) NULL,
    nno_of_floors numeric(18,0) NULL

    )

    declare v_strDeptIds text;
            v_strSubDeptIds text;

BEGIN

        v_strsql := 'SELECT     building.*
FROM         building
        WHERE     (building.nbuilding_inst_id = '|| cast(p_nInstID as varchar(1)) ||')

         ';

         print v_strsql 
         v_strsql1 text;
         v_strsql1 := v_strsql

        Insert into @table1; execute sp_executesql;  v_strsql1 
        select * from @table1;

Return true;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 4:  declare @table1 table
```

Can any one please tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your function actually returns the result of a SELECT query, not a boolean value, so `returns boolean` is wrong to begin with.

To return a result, you need to declare the function as `returns table()`. But as you seem to simply return rows from the `building` table you can define it as `returns setof building`.

Then remove the useless dynamic SQL which seems completely unnecessary.

In PL/pgSQL there are no table variables, and copying the result of a query into one before returning that result from that table seems to be an unnecessary step which only slows down things. In Postgres you simply return the result of the query, there is no need to store it locally.

Additionally: rather than casting a parameter to another type inside the function it's better to declare that parameter with the type you expect.

So the simplified version of that function in PostgreSQL would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ETL_GetBuildingDetailsByUserID ( p_nInstID  text)
  RETURNS setof building
AS $$
    select building.*
    from building
    WHERE  building.nbuilding_inst_id = p_nInstID
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

You can use it  like this:

```
select *
from ETL_GetBuildingDetailsByUserID ('42');
```

---

Unrelated, but: using `numeric(18,0)` for columns that store values without decimals is overkill. You should define those columns as `bigint`. Much faster and uses less space than numeric.

Comment: I have one quation if in selecting all record from building so return type is   `setof building` but if query result is different for example  returns count of record and name of table then what will be RETURNS statement in function

Comment: @SpringUser: then you need to explicitly define the returned columns in the function declaration: `returns table (some_value int, another_value text, ...)`